# Finding distance between corners of AR markers

Tags: c#, math, xna, computer-vision

So far my process is as follows:

Markers are square markers of a known size, an example is below:

[image]

1. Detect markers
2. Get translation + rotation of markers relative to camera using [POSIT](http://www.cfar.umd.edu/~daniel/daniel_papersfordownload/CoplanarPts.pdf) - result is a transformation matrix of the matrix in camera coordinate space.

Now I am trying to find the distance in mm between the related corners of two markers. An example is below:

[image]

By distance I mean the euclidean distance (sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)).

I am thinking it should be possible as I have a reference for mm distance (the edge of any of the markers is a known mm distance), but I am unsure about how I would get to this from just the two transformation matrices I have.

EDIT:

I have managed so far to get the relative distance between the marker centers by multiplying the 2nd transform matrix by the inverse of the first and looking at the translation of the result.

I figured that I can get the plane of each marker by getting the normal and point. From there I should be able to get the 3d coord of a corner by looking at how the 2D point intersects that plane and from there the rest should be easy. I am not entirely sure how to get the normal of the marker and how to work out the point where the 2D coord representing the corner intersects the plane.

Extra info:

- Using XNA and C#
- Using AForge.net for video input and marker detection.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

For calculation simplicity, I will suppose that the markers are on the XY plane. Otherwise, you would have to do some projections to get the camera position into the marker's plane.

Given the translation matrix, you should be able to define the camera position. We will try to find the absolute difference between those point's coordinate

Let's assume pC(xc,yc) the camera position, pA(xa,ya) the first marker position, pB(xb,yb) the second marker position.

lAC the absolute distance between A and the camera, which is known

lBC the absolute distance between B and the camera, which is known

lAB the absolute distance between B and A

dAC(dcax,dcay) the manhattan distance between the camera and A,

dBC(dcbx,dcby) and dAB(dabx,daby) likewise.

dcax = sqrt( lAC^2 - (xc-xa)^2)

dcay = sqrt( lAC^2 - (yc-ya)^2)

dcbx = sqrt( lBC^2 - (xc-xb)^2)

dcby = sqrt( lBC^2 - (yc-yb)^2)

dabx = abs(dcbx-dcax)

daby = abs(dcby-dcay)

lAB = sqrt(dabx^2 + daby^2)

[image]

Ps: It's been a long time since I've done this, Would appreciate a double check :)